# How to control reduction strategy for stateful metric in keras mirrored strategy

Tags: tensorflow, keras, multi-gpu

I use keras `fit()` method with custom metrics passed to model.
The metrics are stateful - i.e. are a subclass of a `Metric`, as described in https://keras.io/api/metrics/#as-subclasses-of-metric-stateful
When I run the code in a multi-gpu environment using a `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()` my metric code is called on every GPU separately with `batch_size/no_of_gpus` examples passed, which is reasonable to expect.

What happens next is that multiple scalars (one from every GPU) of the metric value need to be reduced to a single scalar, and what I get all the time is a `sum` reduction, while I would like to control that.
Keep in mind, that `reduction` parameter is the one of `Loss` in keras, and there is no such thing in the `Metric` class: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/acbc065f8eb2ed05c7ab5c42b5c5bd6abdd2f91f/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L87

(the only crazy thing I tried was to inherit from a `Mean` class that is a subclass of a `Metric` but that didn't change anything)

`reduction` is mentioned in the metrics code, however this is a reduction over multiple accumulated values in a single metric object, and in multi-gpu setting - this is not the case, as every metric works in its own GPU and is somehow aggregated at the end.

The way I debugged it to understand this behaviour was - I was printing the shapes and the results inside `update_state` method of the metric. And then I looked at value of the metric in `logs` object in `on_batch_end` callback.

I tried looking at TF code, but couldn't find the place this is happening.
I would like to be able to control this behaviour - so either pick 'mean' or 'sum' for the metric, or at least know where it is being done in the code.

Edited: I guess this https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39268 sheds some more light on this issue

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same problem as you (and that's why I found your question).

Seeing that it's been 15 days since you asked the question and there are no answers/comments yet, I thought I might share my temporary workaround.

Like you, I also think that a `SUM` reduction has been performed when combining progress over multiple GPUs. What I did is to pass the number of GPUs (e.g. given by the `num_replicas_in_sync` attribute of your `tf.distribute` strategy object) into the `__init__(...)` constructor of your sub-classed metric object, and use it to divide the return value in the `results()` method.

Potentially, you could also use [`tf.distribute.get_strategy()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/get_strategy) from within the metric object to make it "strategy aware", and use the information to decide how to modify the values in an *ad hoc* manner so that the `SUM` reduction will produce what you want.

I hope this helps for now, whether as a suggestion or as a confirmation that you're not alone on this.

Comment: Thanks. I feel better we are not alone and so this problem looks real. I thought about same solution you propose. This is, however, a hack, it breaks the logic of what the 'metric' is and what should be in this class.

Answer (score 1):

When implementing the subclass of the Keras Metric class, you have to override the merge_state() function correctly. If you do not override this function, the default implementation will be used - which is a simple sum.

See: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric